# The proxy server is refusing connections

Tags: proxy, connection

I have downloaded the most recent version of the Tor bundle 6.5.2 for Mac. When I open the Tor browser I get a message "the proxy server is refusing connections". I have followed the instructions (on YouTube and other sites) to set the Preferences>Advanced>Network>Settings>to Manual Proxy Configuration and select SOCKS Host 127.0.0.1 and Port 9150. I don't really know what a 'proxy' is or how to fix this so that i can use the browser.

Comment: You shouldn't be changing the proxy settings, it sounds like something broke during the installation: Uninstall it, delete the `~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data` folder then reinstall the app. (this will remove any bookmarks you have saved on Tor Browser, if any)

Comment: I received this error on Mac OS when I tried to run the browser directly from the DMG instead of copying Tor Browser to Applications. Closing Tor Browser, installing the browser in Applications, and restarting Tor Browser (running from Applications) fixed this error for me.

Comment: See here (tor project bug report): https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9413

Comment: Reinstalling worked for me.
Unfortunately, I changed folder place and name, that's what caused the problem.

Comment: i downloaded tor browser. but it alwways says the proxy sever is refusing connections. Idk what to do. Plus i have seen the above queries...where can i find that application folder? JUst want to get deep into dark web soon..... can"t wait foe it...

Answer (score 5):

So wierd. I faced this problem in my windows. I figured the issue could be similar with my tor browser aswell. The tor browser application is in a new folder in Desktop. Recently I move everything from my desktop to another new folder in my desktop. Started having this issue. I moved the files back to how it was and then tor started working. Bizarre. Hope this helps if anyone else is facing this issue on a windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and then I realized that I ignored the initial pop-up when starting Tor that suggests to move the downloaded `.dmg` file to `Applications` (just as @bradreaves recommends above [in his comment](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14885/the-proxy-server-is-refusing-connections#comment-16881)).

[image]

Just a note to myself, because the `.dmg` file was already in `Applications` when the above window popped up after double clicking the `.dmg`:

1. Click on the Tor Browser icon in the above window
2. Drag it in the Applications folder

Comment: Followed Attila's answer and it worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14732)